# TypeHinting: How to typehint pygame Surface?

Tags: python, pygame, type-hinting, python-typing

Is `-> pygame.Surface:` used correctly or should I do it in another way?

```
import pygame


def get_image() -> pygame.Surface:
    return pygame.image.load(f'img/player.png').convert_alpha()
```

Comment: One way to know is to try `type(pygame.image.load(f'img/player.png').convert_alpha())`

Comment: Yes, this is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at [`pygame.Surface.convert_alpha`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.convert_alpha) it seems that they also use `pygame.Surface` as the resulting type hint from that method.

So I would guess it's correct.

---

```
convert_alpha()
  change the pixel format of an image including per pixel alphas
  convert_alpha(Surface) -> Surface
  convert_alpha() -> Surface
```